# Formula with one of the condition is FALSE other is TRUE

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-manipulation

I have an Excel formula that sums something if 2 conditions are `TRUE`:

```
=SUMIFS(F:F,$A:$A,$A71,$M:$M,$M71)
```

What I was looking for, is actually changing one of those conditions to check if its `FALSE`, so:

Scenario:

> When it finds all records with different value in `A` and same value in `M`

How can I do it?
Thank you for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
=SUMIFS(F:F, $A:$A, "<>"&$A71, $M:$M, $M71)
```

Comment: I had to wait a couple of minutes before it let me